# Handling a False selection from Dialog Box

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to handle a false or no file selection from a dialog box. The rest of the code is working very well but when no file selection is made I receive the following error message from VBA:  1004 False.xlsx could not be found. Do you know how to manage the code to prevent that error message to pop up?

```
Sub OpeningExcelFile2()
    Dim Finfo As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Filename As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim objWdApp As Object
    Dim objWdDoc As Object



    'Setup the list of file filters
    Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xlsx),*xlsx," & _
            "Macro-Enable Worksheet (*.xlsm),*xlsm," & _
            "Word Files (*.docx),*.docx," & _
            "All Files (*.*),*.*"
             MultiSelect = True


    'Display *.* by default
    FilterIndex = 4

    'Set the dialog box caption
    Title = "Select a File to Open"

    'Get the Filename
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, _
        FilterIndex, Title)

    'Handle return info from dialog box

    If Filename = False Then
            MsgBox "No file was selected."
    Else
        MsgBox "You selected " & Filename
    End If

    If InStr(1, Filename, ".docx", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set objWdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWdApp.Visible = True
        Set objWdDoc = objWdApp.Documents.Open(Filename) '\\ Open Word Document

    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename) '\\ Open Excel Spreadsheet

    'how to bring application excel to the front like word in this code?

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no file is selected, exit the subroutine:

```
If Filename = False Then
    MsgBox "No file was selected."
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "You selected " & Filename
End If
```

Comment: That was simply awesome. Thank you very much. The code is working really great now.!